# Array a string in the following format?

Tags: php, string, variables, foreach, explode

How can i array a string, in the format that $_POST does... kind of, well i have this kind of format coming in:

```
101=1&2020=2&303=3
```

(Incase your wondering, its the result of jQuery Sortable Serialize...
I want to run an SQL statement to update a field with the RIGHT side of the = sign, where its the left side of the equal sign? I know the SQL for this, but i wanted to put it in a format that i could use the foreach($VAR as $key=>$value) and build an sql statement from that.. as i dont know how many 101=1 there will be?

I just want to explode this in a way that $key = 101 and $value = 1

Sounds confusing ;)
Thanks so so much in advanced!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$input = "101=1&2020=2&303=3";
$output = array();
$exp = explode('&',$input);
foreach($exp as $e){
   $pair = explode("=",$e);
   $output[$pair[0]] = $pair[1];
}
```

Answer (score 5):

See the [`parse_str`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) function.

Answer (score 3):

It's not the most intuitive function name in PHP but the function you're looking for is [parse_str()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php). You can use it like this:

```
$myArray = array();
parse_str('101=1&2020=2&303=3', $myArray);
print_r($myArray);
```

Comment: nice, I had no idea about this! very useful function, and one I'm sure has been rewritten thousands of times by people that didn't know about it.

Answer (score 1):

One quick and dirty solution:

```
<?php
$str = "101=1&2020=2&303=3";
$VAR = array();
foreach(explode('&', $str) AS $pair)
{
    list($key, $value) = each(explode('=', $pair));
    $VAR[$key] = $value;
}
?>
```

Comment: @JP: no need to reinvent the wheel. PHP has this functionality built-in: parse_str();

Comment: Kudos! Just haven't coded in PHP for a while, forgot about this one; plus isn't the semantic behind the name parse_str() a bit wide? :)

Comment: @JP: Does it really surprise you to see a badly named function in the PHP standard library? :)

Comment: @Lukas: Oh wait, it's "standard"? :p

Answer (score 1):

```
parse_str($query_string, $array_to_hold_values);
```

Answer (score 0):

Explode on the & to get an array that contains [ 101=1 , 2020=2 , 303=3 ] then for each element, split on the = and push the key/value pair onto a new array.